# POST new value using ng-change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm attempting to fire off a POST request upon selection of an option within my Angular app. Below is my current code.

HTML:

```
<select ng-options="option for option in linked.maxOptions" ng-model="linked.selectedMax" ng-change="linked.changeMax()"></select>
```

Controller:

```
var playerId = $routeParams.playerId;

vm.changeMax = function() {
  playersService.setMaxPoints({
    playerId: playerId,
    max: vm.selectedMax
  }).$promise.then(function(res){
    return res.success;
  }, function(res) {
    alert('Couldn\'t update number of points to ' + vm.selectedMax + ':' + res.success);
  });
};
```

Service:

```
angular.module('gameApp')
  .factory('playersService', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
      var base = '/api/players/:playerId/';
      return $resource(base, {}, {
        setMaxPoints: {method: 'POST', url: base + 'maxPoints/' + ':max'}
      });
    }]);
```

The problem is that my parameters are not being passed to my service method for some reason as it attempts to hit this endpoint:

```
http://localhost:3010/api/players/maxPoints
```

Answer (score 1):

Where does `playerId` come from? It's not declared nor passed as a parameter to your `changeMax` function.

Here is how I declare resources. The syntax is a bit easier than yours so it's less error prone:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .factory('ActivityData', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/service/data/:userEmail/:dataType', {dataType: 'all'},
      {   
        getTotals: {method:'GET', cache: true, params: { dataType: 'total'}}
      }

  });
```

Comment: Sorry, edited my question. I grab `playerId` from the `$routeParams' and set it before this method. Seems to be something about the way I'm passing parameters to my service method that's messing things up. My GET requests work well, but not POST.

Comment: Have you tried to use $routeParams.playerId directly in the resource?

Comment: Just solved it, going to post the solution below for others' benefit.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in my controller. I was handling a POST request just like I handle GET requests which apparently does not work. I needed to pass a second, in this case empty, object to my service method call to get things working. I believe this is where you would pass any 'body' of data to your service call:

```
vm.changeMax = function() {
  playersService.setMaxPoints({
    playerId: playerId,
    max: vm.selectedMax
  }, {}).$promise.then(function(res){
    return res.success;
  }, function(res) {
    alert('Couldn\'t update number of points to ' + vm.selectedMax + ':' + res.success);
  });
};
```